# Dual monitors not working on Ubuntu 21.10 - Nvidia GPU on ROG Zephyrus M15

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, laptop

my laptop is not recognizing any external monitors over HDMI after updating from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.10. (I also tried screen sharing on Google Meet and got a black screen when sharing the entire monitor, probably related)

I tried running Nvidia 470 and 495 drivers. Main graphics driver shows up as Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2). The laptop has a i7-10750H and an RTX 2070 Super MaxQ.

```
$ uname -r
5.13.0-21-generic

$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F14sv00001043sd0000174Fbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile / Max-Q Refresh]
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-495 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*XWAYLAND0 1920/340x1080/190+0+0  XWAYLAND0

$ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:1866 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0951:16b7 Kingston Technology HyperX Alloy FPS Mechanical Gaming Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 2109:0103 VIA Labs, Inc. USB 2.0 BILLBOARD             
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0bda:525a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. FHD Webcam
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1532:0016 Razer USA, Ltd DeathAdder 3.5G
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1a40:0801 Terminus Technology Inc. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am tech savy enough to understand most responses but fairly new to ubuntu, so please advise with step by step instructions when possible, since I've run into issues before with statements like "update the kernel".

On an unrelated note the laptop runs the fans constantly and is pretty hot on idle, I'd appreciate any suggestions on any tools I should be getting .

Thanks!